# In phpunit how to send a post request redirectly?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am developing a php interface program．I want to use phpunit to send a post or get request to the interface. How to send a post request redirectly?

Comment: What does *"redirectly"* mean? Do you want to redirect with HTTP 301 after a POST request?